# Render form elements separately

Tags: forms, 8

How to render custom form's `$form['#action']` property in the controller's template when it actually contains some random string like `form_id_66dbsfds` ?

Comment: You ask "Does anyone know how to get this thing done?" What do you mean by "thing"? You also ask "How should I get form action path?" Do you want to change the form action path? This is not recommended because you would need to replicate all the form handling that Drupal gives you in order to be secure. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, there is no need to change the #action path.

Comment: People, I was just making a form more customized by rendering fileds separately.
When I tried to get action path from the form object I got that strange id string, but not the path. This is the problem.
Solved by using current url, but I think there should be a way of getting form action from the form object. Just didn't manage to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous answer is not an answer for my question.
1. `{{ form['#action'] }}` returns a string, which is not a url string, this is some kind of a route, but url generator does not recognize it.
2. If there's a need to render a form separately by the fields in a template - never use `#markup`, always use `#theme` and variables.
3. I did this like that:

```
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $route = $request->attributes->get('_route');
    $routeParams = $request->attributes->get('_raw_variables')->all();
    $currentPath = $this->get('url_generator')->generate($route, $routeParams);
```

To get a current url. And then:

```
<form id="{{ form['#id'] }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="{{ form['#method'] }}" action="{{ currentPath }}">
```

The question was - how to get a proper action string from the form object.

Answer (score 3):

I tried below code to render form in my controller class and it is working fine

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\hollywood\Form\Hollywood');
$form = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($form);

$content['exposed_filter'] = array(
  '#markup' => $form,
);

return $content;
```

Drupal\hollywood\Form\Hollywood is a namespace of the class.

Comment: Yes, this works pretty great, but what if you want to customize form template and rendering fields separately from the form object.
For example:
`<div>{{ form.name }}</div><div>{{ form.message }}</div>`
How to generate a form tag, with a proper action attribute ?

Comment: @EvgeniyMonakov did you ever find a solution to this? I would like to know how to do this as well.

Comment: I wrote a twig extension function for it. See the answer beneath.